# composing with a non-flat morphism

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X,Y,Z$ be integral schemes and $f:X\to Y$, $g:Y\to Z$ be morphisms such that $g$ is flat and $f$ is not flat. Does this imply that the composition $g\circ f:X\to Z$ is necessarily non-flat?

[EDIT: ykm's example works but I'm also interested to know the answer in the case where $X,Y,Z$ have the same dimension].

Comment: Whoops, I didn't see the word integral.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Take $Z=Spec k$ where $k$ is a field. Everything is flat over a field.

Comment: Thanks! what if I take $X,Y,Z$ to have the same dimension?

Comment: @adrido I don't think that will change the answer. In general, if $g \circ f$ is flat and $g$ is unramified, then $f$ is flat. Requiring $g$ to be flat does not warrant this conclusion.

Comment: @c_c_chaos: thanks!